# Firewall detects strange ip's (hosts) in the network

Tags: networking, router, security, firewall, internet-filter

I need your suggestion.
My router antispoofing detects and blocks the ip's like: 10.211.87.139; 10.209.198.166; 10.25.59.222. I'm not using these subnets, I tried to set my adater as static with given subnets and scanned (pinged, traced), but can't find them...
Can you suggest me how to find and discover, who or what is spreading that ip's?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Routers don't normally monitor things that go on within the broadcast domain(s), such as its "LAN side". My guess is the traffics are from the WAN side.

Comment: What devices do you have on your network?  I have Vivo cameras on my network that keep trying to use a different IP address, all the time, despite being told in their setup which IP address to use.  Only you know what you have installed.  How do you know they are hosts?